# MongoDB filter recursively nested Array by object field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass, nosql-aggregation

I want to filter a nested object array by a field in mongoDb Compass.

Here is an example collection.

```
{
    "_id": "MENU_ORDER_POS_1",
    "menuVersion": "MENU_ORDER",
    "menuType": "MAIN",
    "status": "ENABLED",
    "children": [
        {
            "_id": "MENU_ORDER_CHILD_1",
            "menuVersion": "MENU_ORDER",
            "status": "ENABLED",
            "children": [
                {
                    "_id": "MENU_ORDER_CHILD_1.1",
                    "menuVersion": "MENU_ORDER",
                    "status": "ENABLED",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "_id": "MENU_ORDER_CHILD_1.2",
                    "menuVersion": "MENU_ORDER",
                    "status": "DISABLED",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "MENU_ORDER_CHILD_2",
            "menuVersion": "MENU_ORDER",
            "status": "DISABLED",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "MENU_ORDER_CHILD_3",
            "menuVersion": "MENU_ORDER",
            "status": "DISABLED",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "MENU_ORDER_POS_2",
    "menuVersion": "PANEL",
    "menuType": "",
    "defaultPath": "",
    "eventNameToNavigate": "",
    "status": "ENABLED",
    "children": []
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "_id": "MENU_ORDER_POS_1",
    "menuVersion": "MENU_ORDER",
    "menuType": "MAIN",
    "status": "ENABLED",
    "children": [
        {
            "_id": "MENU_ORDER_CHILD_1",
            "menuVersion": "MENU_ORDER",
            "status": "ENABLED",
            "children": [
                {
                    "_id": "MENU_ORDER_CHILD_1.1",
                    "menuVersion": "MENU_ORDER",
                    "status": "ENABLED",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Aggregate stages**

1. First I need to get all the documents with `menuVersion = "MENU_ORDER"` and `status = "ENABLED"`.
2. Then I need to filter all nested items in the children Array, note that this array is recursive and can have multiple children object inside an item. I need to get all the children items that matches `status = "ENABLED"`

**Note** The children array can have elements with the children object and this can be infinite, it is multilevel and all the items in the nested array must meet the filter criteria

I figure aggregate is the best choice here, using match and filter should do the job but I can't figure how to make it infinite recursive to filter all N child in the array.

So far I have written the filter part.

```
{
  children: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$children",
      as: "children",
      cond: {
        $eq: "children.status", "ENABLED"      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could recursively descend `"children"` by using a recursive Javascript `"$function"`.  I like @ray's idea of a different data/collection model where `"$graphLookup"` could be used effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using `$filter` is correct. You just need to refer the variable you set (i.e. children) using `$$`. Repeat it again with the inner array.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      children: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$children",
          "as": "c",
          "cond": {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$c.menuVersion",
                  "MENU_ORDER"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$c.status",
                  "ENABLED"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      children: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$children",
          "as": "c",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$c",
              {
                "children": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$c.children",
                    "as": "innerChild",
                    "cond": {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$innerChild.status",
                        "ENABLED"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YwbCGwS5Fej)

Comment: It works as expected but It only filters up to level 2 of a nested child, In my case the nested child can be infinite, there is no limit to the nested level. Is there a way to have an aggregate that can filter a nested N times object child?

Comment: @KevinValdez I don't think there is such a way. And you should not have uncertain and indefinite nesting levels. If you are having a recursive nature, you can consider storing the document in individual documents and use `$graphLookup` to construct the recursive structure.